# Move (cut-paste) a File in Windows Server using Chef

Tags: windows, automation, chef-infra

I want to move a file from one location to another in Windows Server using Chef.
I am passing the Target Directory as Variable, its not working... any pointers

```
directory_name = e:\\temp
execute 'copy_MSlog' do
  command move "E:\\Test\\Untitled.png #{directory_name}"
end
```

Comment: And this will fail on next run because the source doesn't exist anymore... Moreover your actual code shouldn't compile because the "e:\\temp" is not quote when defining the directory_name. Give background about your actual goal, there's maybe another way to tackle the problem.

Comment: @Tensibai, here is the actual goal...., I have a log file in E:/App/Wind/logs/LCS.log which keeps increasing on daily basis, my aim is to stop the App server, move the log file from E:/App/Wind/logs to F:/Archive/Log_<TimeStamp>, Here the Log_<Timestamp> is a variable and generated in chef code

Comment: that's a task for a scheduled task, not for Chef. Chef can be used to set up the task itself. Something like logrotate under Linux (I did an ugly port o'ce. But there's probably more professional tools existing)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately file moves with Chef are a bit dicey since they are difficult to make idempotent and convergent. You need to fix your quoting but otherwise you're on the right track. Use some `not_if` or `only_if` guards to ensure idempotence and you should be all set.